# replace value for atIndex dynamically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
NSDictionary *item = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               eyeNameHolder,@"eye",
                               lipsNameHolder,@"lips",nil];

NSMutableArray *arrayItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:item];
[arrayItems insertObject:item atIndex:dynamical variable];
[arrayItems writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```

how can i replace the value of atIndex dynamically by sending different values from 0 to 10 through tapping different buttons from 0 to 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` has `replaceObjectsAtIndex:withObject:`, try something like:

```
[arrayItems replaceObjectsAtIndex:atIndex withObject:/*0-10*/];
```

Comment: sorry, i don't understand how this work?would you like to explain more? will this cause my item1,item2 storing the same value at different index?i mean my plist suppose to be like this:  

    <dict>
     <key>item1</key>
     <dict>
      <key>eye</key>
      <string>eye_blue</string>
      <key>lips</key>
      <string>lips_blue</string>
     </dict>
     <key>item2</key>
     <dict>
      <key>eye</key>
      <string>eye_green</string>
      <key>lips</key>
      <string>lips_green</string>
     </dict>
     <key>items</key>
     <array/>
    </dict>

Comment: `replaceObjectsAtIndexes:withObjects:` is simply described as **Replaces the *object* at index with *anObject*.** See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:

Answer (score 0):

i did something like below, it works fine.

```
AppDelegate* ref = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSMutableDictionary *item = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               eyeNameHolder,@"eye",
                               lipsNameHolder,@"lips",nil];

[arrayItems replaceObjectAtIndex:ref.IndexerHolder withObject:item];
        [arrayItems writeToFile:finalPath atomically:YES];
```